# Custom Settings with ApplicationSettingsBase saving List of custom objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, settings

I am trying to use `ApplicationSettingsBase` with saving list of custom objects. Here is my application settings class:

```
internal class ApplicationSettings: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [DefaultSettingValue(""), UserScopedSetting]
    public List<MyAwesomeClass> MyObjects
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return this["MyObjects"] as    List<MyAwesomeClass>;
            }
            catch (SettingsPropertyNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }             
        }
    }

    public void Add(MyAwesomeClass val)
    {
        MyObjects.Add(val);
        this["MyObjects"] =  MyObjects;
    }
}
```

Here is my custom class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyAwesomeClass 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeStringProperty{ get; set; }
    public bool SomeBooleanProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
_applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings();
_applicationSettings.Add(new MyAwesomeClass {/*Some initial values*/});
_applicationSettings.Save();
```

But when application restarts _applicationSettings.MyObjects is always have zero count. I don't know why my list doesn't want saving. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate the property with `[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]`:

```
[DefaultSettingValue(""), UserScopedSetting]
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
public List<MyAwesomeClass> MyObjects
```

> [Application Settings Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1(v=vs.110).aspx) » Setting Persistence » Settings Serialization
>   If you implement your own settings class, you can use the
>   [`SettingsSerializeAsAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to mark a setting for either binary or
>   custom serialization using the [`SettingsSerializeAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeas(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration.