# storing ListViewItems to 1 settings item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In my application i have a ListView that contains a list of items with a simple name and tag.
I want to store this some way in the application and i prefer storing them some way into the Properties.Settings.
I though about storing it as a string, but the items in the listview can contain any type of characters, so using a character to split the string into items is not fail proof.

Is it somehow possible to store a listview with items and tags into the Properties.Settings? Either as some kind of string or some other way ?

Comment: Assuming the tag is a string, You can store a `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` in `Properties.Settings` where the name can store the text and the tag is stored in the value.

Comment: @ZoharPeled this is very weird. Im using the NameValueCollection and i save the properties. When the application is still active, i can save and load from the settings and it all works fine. But once the application closes and restarts, the load does not work as if it was not saved....

Comment: @Dante1986 you called `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` ?

Comment: @Dante1986 do you manage other settings, that do work ? When restarting your app ?

Comment: @Jim yes. check my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086762/namevaluecollection-doesnt-save-to-properties-settings  (closing this one)  And yes, it did work for simple strings that i saved

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Custom Settings with ApplicationSettingsBase saving List of custom objects in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334532/custom-settings-with-applicationsettingsbase-saving-list-of-custom-objects-in-c)