# NameValueCollection doesnt save to Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

I added an entry in the `Properties.Settings` named `strCol` that is of type `NameValueCollection`. I am using this to save items from a listview to the settings so that when the application reboots, the ListView gets re-populated again with the items that were saved previously. I'm only storing the item name and the tag from the ListViewItems.

But something strange is happening I cant explain.

**I am using this code to save the items to the settings:**

```
NameValueCollection nvCol = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (ListViewItem lviP in lvParmNames.Items)
{
    nvCol.Add(lviP.Text, lviP.Tag.ToString());
}
Properties.Settings.Default.strCol = nvCol;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

For some reason the Save and load in and from settings works fine, as long as the application is still active. But when the application has been closed and rebooted, the load doesn't work as if the `NameValueCollection` was not saved.

What am I missing here ?

**How I'm currently loading the setting:**

The call for loading, but it already seem to fail at the check if its null

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.strCol != null)      
{        
    NameValueCollection nv = Properties.Settings.Default.strCol;
    foreach (string key in nv)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = nv[key];
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(key);
            lvi.Tag = value;
            lvFamNames.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("Error", "Error while parsing Family Names from saved settings. \n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Just noticed something:**

[image: settings]

Though i added the NameValueCollection in the sections it is actually not added when building the application. When i open the config file, the setting is not there.
So i guess the issue is here, though now i need to figure out how to add it now.

Looking into the `Settings.Designer.cs` file, i guess this part looks wrong for the type of 'NameValueCollection`:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public global::System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection strColExcelFamNames {
        get {
            return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)(this["strCol"]));
        }
        set {
            this["strCol"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When are you loading the data?  When are you saving the data?  What are you saving in the Tag property?

Comment: Save should happen when user presses button "Save settings" and load should happen at startup of the app. Tag is  used to store a number that represents an ElementId